# Which Python 2.7.x Version contains the fix for issue1625

Tags: python

I think I have a Python2.7 installation where this issue is still alive:

http://bugs.python.org/issue1625 (bz2.BZ2File doesn't support multiple streams)

Which Python 2.7 version contains the fix? I could not find it on above page.

Comment: None, it's only fixed in 3.3 and above. See the comments starting http://bugs.python.org/issue1625#msg144445; this won't patched in 2.7. You can use the [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bz2file), instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/ad20324229f4, you should be using the bz2file module on pypi to get this fix.